# Regarding 2 prepositions, with or by

Tags: word-choice

I am afraid this question might sound like 7th grades' question.

For, example, when I would like to say,

> Let's learn English **utilizing** movie songs

which preposition should I use if I would like to place a preposition
in replace of the **utilizing** part, namely, **with** or **by**?

( I am writing for my personal business purpose but I sincerely would not
  like to make this kind of mistake which personally comes out of my pride...
 ( Although I have to ask... ))

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Regards.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use *with* or *by*? *using* would be much better.

Comment: Ugh....only because it is short...( I think )...

Comment: But some prepositions have so many uses (and misuses), it might be better to use one that is more specific in meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two patterns you are asking about are

> Let's learn English **with** movie songs.

the pattern is

> **with** + *noun*

where *noun* is the instrument used for the action.

> Let's learn English **with** native speakers.
>   Let's learn English **with** Youtube videos.
>   Let's write **with** a pencil.

Otherwise, one might say

> **by** + *verbing* + *noun*
>
> Let's learn English **by** *singing* movie songs.
>
> Let's learn English **by** *talking* with native speakers.
>   Let's learn English **by** *watching* Youtube videos.
>   Let's write **by** *using* a pencil.

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer. So in summary, by is more **prone** to be used when we or I are emphasizing the **action**??

Comment: The action of *how* you are *learning* (***by*** *way of*).

Comment: Such said, you are kindly trying to tell me that, may be, particularly in this case, the movie is **more like** the **instrument** rather than your **by way of** ? ( Hence, I need to insert **listening to** or some kind of such verb-noun if I would like to use **by** here. ) I apologize for sticking so much (m_m).

Comment: Yes, an ambiguity appears without the *verbing* which is "Let's learn English by Youtube videos." may be understood to mean "the Youtube  videos' form of English",  "English by Youtube" = "Youtube English". "by listening to Youtube videos" is unambiguous.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. With millions of appreciations. (m_m).